# Azure Monitor Logs: The AppServiceHTTPLogs table is missing the CsUriQuery field?

Tags: azure-monitoring, iis-logs

I'm trying to get some raw log-data from the **AppServiceHTTPLogs** table by using Azure > Monitor > Logs.

As it turns out, the AppServiceHTTPLogs table doesn't seem to have the **CsUriQuery** column, which is weird.

For example, the query: 
*AppServiceHTTPLogs | project CsUriStem* 
.. returns requested file names as expected, but the query:

*AppServiceHTTPLogs| project CsUriQuery*
.. returns error (Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'CsUriQuery')

Why's that? Is the CsUriQuery column totally missing at the AppServiceHTTPLogs table?

Also, a weird thing is that another table, **W3CIISLog**, has the column in place (csUriQuery) but that table, when queried with the Monitor, returns no rows at all (missing data)?!

Any comments? Thanks.